# Should I report "Thank you" comments as obsolete?

Tags: discussion, comments

Should I do something about these types of comments? I saw like 3 "Thank you" comments in a single post today.

Should I report it? Ignore it? Or what?

Comment: Ignore it. Such comments (and their equivalent in questions) are fair game when cleaning up or editing something *anyway*, but there is no point in alerting mods to something that doesn't actively bother anyone.

Comment: @Generic you're very welcome.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for giving positive feedback to a user's positive feedback.